# Populating ArrayList with elements on Hashtable

Tags: java

How to populate an arrayList with elements on Hashtable?

```
private Hashtable<Client,ArrayList<Hapsira>> reservation;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You either `get` the list and `add` to it or create a `new` one and `put` it in the hash table.

Comment: Besides the fact that A) hashtable is seriously outdated (use HashMap and forget about Hashtable B) your question is unclear (what do you want in that list: the keys, the values, both? ... there are really zillions and zillions of similar questions here that would tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create Client object
- Create empty ArrayList
- Put objects in ArrayList
- Store ArrayList for client object as key
- Retrieve ArrayList from Hashable by client object as a key

Example:

```
Hashtable<Client, ArrayList<Hapsira>> reservation = new Hashtable<>();
Client client = new Client();
ArrayList<Hapsira> list = new ArrayList<>();
Hapsira hapsira = new Hapsira();
list.add(hapsira);
reservation.put(client, list);

System.out.println(reservation.get(client));
```